# Create a ContainerControl with padding included

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I want to create a control that contains a 25px Header. When I add child controls I want them to behave like they would be used in a GroupBox. 
When a control's DockStyle is set to Fill in a groupbox, it's location is automatically set to `3;16` and it's size to `Width-6; Height-19`.
I do not wan't to use Padding or Margin, as they seem not to be used in GroupBox.

How could I achieve same behavior in my own controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the DisplayRectangle property of a panel:

```
public class MyContainer : Panel {

  public override Rectangle DisplayRectangle {
    get {
      int headerHeight = 25;
      return new Rectangle(
        this.Padding.Left,
        this.Padding.Top + headerHeight,
        this.ClientSize.Width - 
          (this.Padding.Left + this.Padding.Right),
        this.ClientSize.Height - 
          (this.Padding.Top + this.Padding.Bottom + headerHeight));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, althouth I found it on my own already. Works great!